# How to repeat title in tcolorbox?

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox

```
\centering
\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw, width=7cm, left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,boxrule=2pt, colback=white}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title=Titulo ] %, boxsep=-4mm
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
   paragraph \\
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the `title after break` option. Since my knowledge of Spanish is limited I just chose `Titulo -- continuado` ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\centering

\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw, width=7cm, left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,boxrule=2pt, colback=white}


\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title={Titulo},title after break={Titulo -- continuado}] 
\blindtext[10]   
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The screen shot shows (parts) of two following pages, the black line in between is a separator introduced by Adobe Reader only, it's not in the actual output.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome ... Take a look into the very exhaustive `tcolorbox` documentation. You'll find basically everything there